# Verilog HDL: Having nested if inside reset condition is synthesizable?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

```
always @ (posedge clock or negedge reset_l)   //Active low asyn reset
begin
    if(!reset_l)
    begin
        if(enable)
        begin
            status <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        if(enable)
        begin
            status <= 1'b1;
        end
    end
end
```

I am running synthesis using  Synopsis Design Compiler. I am getting  warning at line 5 that enable is read but not mentioned in the sensitivity list.

My doubt is can reset if-loop  can  have   nested if's ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this - if `reset_l` is active, and `enable` is not active, then the clock is ignored even though the device isn't being reset. This shouldn't synthesise, and your gate-level and RTL sims won't match if it does. how about this recoding:

```
   assign rst2 = !reset_l & enable;
   always @(posedge clock or posedge rst2)
     if(rst2)
       status <= 0;
     else if(enable)
       status <= 1;
```